# Protractor : Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to test a href link. I am getting the error message given below when I am trying to run my protractor script. I went through the earlier solutions like it might be because of the missing brackets but could not figure anything missing. I am new to protractor, can someone guide me what is wrong with my code.

test_spec.js

```
describe('test data collections link',function(){

    it("to click and test data collections link",funtion(){

        browser.get("http://localhost:7001/xxx/#/");

        element(by.id('dataCollection')).click();       
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:7001/xxx/#/dataCollection");
    });
});
```

conf.js

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome'
},



// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
// protractor is called.
specs: ['test_spec.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
};
```

error occurs when 'protractor conf.js' is executed:

```
[launcher] Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at C:\Users\gsr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:63:5
at Array.forEach (native)
at Jasmine.loadSpecs (C:\Users\gsr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:62:18)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo. It is not `funtion`, it should be `function`:

```
describe('test data collections link',function(){
    //                                        HERE v
    it("to click and test data collections link",funtion(){

        browser.get("http://localhost:7001/xxx/#/");

        element(by.id('dataCollection')).click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:7001/xxx/#/dataCollection");
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't `funtion` a feature of EMAScript6 ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum it definitely should be. We need to submit a feature request.